How to add Object Data Property in Driver?
I tried using > Single Property, Select Object/mesh then use head_l, and to replicate BPY used ['head_l'] and also 'head_l' nothing worked.
Please don't mind the BPY Code, rn I'm focusing on the Driver.
More Info: I have made a custom property "head_l" in object data properties. I want to use this as Driver in Material Nodes. However I am unable to do so.


This was very confusing, but this might not be working because the custom property is a Boolean and you’re trying to interpret it as an integer. Python itself can do this, but Blender shader nodes might not.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Right-click source "Copy as New Driver", right-click target "Paste Driver".

thanks to Markus' comment, I could figure out what was wrong. Markus' comment also answers the question.
Markus's method 1 :hover over property > copy as new driver > right click where you want to use driver > paste as driver. This will work.
method 2: Add a new driver > Single Property (Mesh Property) > ["prop"]
use " for props, idk why it didn't work with ' for me.

Oh yeah, I have fallen victim to the single quotation mark many times. It must be a double quotation in a driver variable.

"idk why it didn't work with ' for me" - well, for the simple reason it does not work with ', only with "   When you right-click the property and choose Copy Data Path or use the shortcut Shift+Ctrl+C while hovering your mouse over it, you'll get the property name with the correct quotation marks and brackets, you don't have to type it yourself.

If you do not specifically require it to be a driver, why not simply use the Attribute node in the shader? No fussing around with data paths, quotation marks etc. Just make sure you have set the Type to Object and the property name is spelled correctly:


Well, the data was needed from multiple objects for the calculations so I don't think this would've worked.

@Satyam You needed the data from multiple objects combined in a single shader? Or a single property from one object used on multiple objects? That wasn't clear from the question. Or do you mean you have multiple objects, each has a property "head_l" and each object needs to reference its specific individual property? That's what I would do with this setup. As long as they have the property with this name, they can use the same material.

data from multiple objects combined into a single shader.
